# Highcharts: how to change text and background colors

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm new to Highcharts and I'm using a very simple Highcharts bar chart that shows two columns stacked horizontally.  I would like to change the background color and the font colors.  The documentation shows examples like this:

```
Highcharts.setOptions({
    chart: {
        style: {
            fontFamily: 'monospace',
            color: "#f00"
        }
        etc . . .
```

But Highcharts.setOptions doesn't help with the javascript code I am using:

```
    <div id="container" style="width:100%; height:400px;"></div>

    <script>
    $(function () { 
        var myChart = Highcharts.chart('container', {
            chart: {type: 'bar'},
            title: {text: 'Chart Title'},
            xAxis: {categories: ['Category1<br>Category2']},
            yAxis: {title: {text: 'Value'}
            },

            series: [{name: 'Cat1',data: [4.2]},
            {name: 'Cat2',data: [5691.7]}]
        });
    });
    </script>
```

If I simply insert a background-color directive (background-color: #000000) below yAxis the graph disappears from the screen.

So my question is how I can change the text and background colors in the Highcharts js code shown above.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't write `background-color: #000000` but `'background-color': '#000000'` or `backgroundColor: '#000000'` will works

```
chart: {
  type: 'bar',
  backgroundColor: '#000000',
  style: {
    fontFamily: 'monospace',
    color: "#f00" // This line won't work. You must set color for each element like title, axis labels ...
  }
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k4z9g7pf/1/)

Comment: Core972, Thanks very much for the example code you posted on Fiddle.  It works for me, but I don't see both bars at the same time.  I'm working on it now, but if you can tell me why, I'd be really grateful.  Thanks again for your help.

Comment: BTW, it's a logarithmic scale, so I changed  your code to: yAxis: {
    title: {
      text: 'Time in Seconds - Logarithmic Scale',
      type: 'logarithmic',
 color: '#FFFFFF'
    } but no logarithmic scale

Comment: @RTC222 , I updated the fiddle with a logarithmic axis and it's works

Comment: Thanks very much.  I also got very good help on the Highcharts forum.